# Даси, веси, еси, яси

Tags: этимология, славянизмы, историческая-грамматика

Читая острожскую библию заметил созвучность форм второго лица единственного числа "даси", "веси", "еси", "яси" образованных от глаголов дати, ведети, быти и ясти.
Существовал ли ранее особый третий тип спряжения аналогичный изменению глагола быти по лицам и числам в настоящем времени?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448667/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все глаголы, которые вы перечислили, в старославянском языке относятся к особому нетематическому классу (нетематический значит, что формы наст. вр. образовывались без участия тематических гласных типа **а** в пис-**а**-ть). Вот как они спрягались:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Из учебника М. Л. Ремнёвой)

Comment: То есть дамь (дам) и даси (дашь) это настоящее время?

Comment: @prostorech дамь и даси — это 1 и 2 л. ед. ч. наст. вр.

Comment: на представленном Вами скриншоте у двойственного числа перепутаны местами 2-е и 3-е лицо